# Console Application doesn't display output, but renaming it does

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, console-application

I have a simple Console Application, which uses Enterprise Framework 5 to call a Stored Procedure and create a text file.

The very first line in this Console application's `main()` is

```
 Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
```

Built this in Release mode; tested it in a test machine and it executes fine.

I copied this `MyApp.exe` and related `.dll`s to production machine, (with different config values of course); in the command prompt there, when this exe is executed, it simply completes the execution without any output. There is no clue as to what happened.

Then I rename `MyApp.exe` to `1MyApp.exe`; when executed, now it displays `starting....` followed by some exception, which I will ask about in another question if necessary.

My question is, why does renaming and executing present an output, whereas the execution with the original name of the application does not produce any output?

Thank you.

Comment: Because you actually execute something else?

Comment: One reason could be this row somewhere in `Main`: `if(args[0].EndWith(@"\MyApp.exe") return;`.

Comment: Check your task manager, is MyApp.exe still running or hung?

Comment: Task mgr indicates .exe is not hung or running; also, there is no line in code that checks the .exe's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine()` buffers its output (for performance reasons)
and flushes it only (becomes visible in console) if it is idle.

Use `Console.Error.WriteLine()` if you want to see the text immediately.

Comment: Or try [`Console.Out.Flush();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the end of the program, but this probably wont work because for `Console.Out`, [`AutoFlush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to true, which should flush after each call to `Console.Write`